# windowActionBar exception

Tags: android, toolbar, illegalstateexception

I receive next exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

I get exception when I call :

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

MainActivity extends from AppCompatActivity. 
My app style :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_items_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

This is my toolbar :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_height">
```

And toolbar style :

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></style>`. As the exception reads "Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead." means your Theme is not being applied.

or

just add the line `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` to your app style. Hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: Can you check in your manifest to see if the theme that you have defined is being set to the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Your Toolbar don't have an **id**

Add your id and try again

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:id=”@+id/toolbar_actionbar”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_height">
```

Comment: It has : " android:id=”@+id/toolbar_actionbar”"

Comment: @CVS I don't see the "id" in your Toolbar xml file?